# Client Hyper-V in Windows 8 : Synthetic Ethernet Port: Failed to finish reserving resources

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am unable to run any of my virtual machines with a network connection.

I get this error when I try to start them:

```
Synthetic Ethernet Port: Failed to finish reserving resources with 
Error 'Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.' 
(0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID 8787....-....-....-....-........)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

This is an error from the Hyper-V Manager, in my case, in Windows 8 pro, but also possible to occur in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that my VMs somehow had two virtual ethernet adaptors, one of which was mapped to an adapter that had been removed from the "Virtual Switch Manager".

Right clicking on the settings, locating the second adaptor, then going to the right side
of the screen and clicking the Remove button below the Network Adaptor's configurat 
properties list, solved the problem.

The error message could be better. Maybe it could say:

"You have two ethernet ports on this VM. Network adaptor #2, has an invalid configuration. Repair or remove the broken network adapter and try again."

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual HBA on Hyper-V has 2 ports, even if you are not able to ping over FC the 2nd port you have to set zoning and presentation for. The 2nd port is used for Live Migration.

BTW: you have to create 2 Virtual SAN and assign just one fabric to one virtual SAN. Also, be careful that the definition on all cluster nodes for NPIV address are the same. Otherwise you will probably not see the presented drives.

Comment: You are talking about something completely unrelated, I think.